# How to handle passing an array of derived class as argument in a function that accepts array of base class?

Tags: c++, arrays, polymorphism, pass-by-reference, slice

I have below sample code with 2 classes:

```
class B {
public:
    int b;
};

class D : public B {
public:
    int d;
};
```

And I have a function that accepts B as an array and sums up the b members:

```
int sum(B a[], int count){

    int sum = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        sum += a[i].b;
    }

    return sum;
}
```

And here is my main:

```
int main() {

    D* a = new D[3];

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        a[i].b = i+1;

    cout << "Sum is " << sum(a, 3) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

What I know is this code does not work because of slicing. I don't get the correct output which should be 6. I tried to get the argument in sum function as:

```
int sum(B& a[], int count)
```

to pass a by reference, but this gets a compile error because you can't use an array of references.

My question is what is the best way to do this?

Currently my solution is to declare my array as:

```
B* a = new D[3];
```

But its not totally clear why it doesn't work well with the previous implementation.

Comment: Use a `virtual` class `D` and a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<B>>`

Comment: Can you explain why make class D virtual? Also I was looking for a solution that won't use vector or unique_ptr but thank you for your answer

Comment: Give `B` a `virtual` destructor. That's what is called runtime polymorphism.

Comment: "I was looking for a solution that won't use vector or unique_ptr". You can use raw arrays and raw pointers instead, though this is not recommended. You cannot pass an array of derived class objects to a function that accepts an array of base class objects. This is just not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `D` array will never look like a `B` array because those types have different sizes. A `D` has a bigger size than a `B`, and hence consecutive elements in a `D` array will be spaced farther apart (because each element takes more space) than consecutive elements in a `B` array.

If you want subtyping polymorphism to work, you need to be using pointers (or references), not the object type itself. You can't have an array of references so you must use an array of pointers.

Something like this will work:

```
int sum(B *a[], int count) {

    int sum = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        sum += a[i]->b;
    }

    return sum;
}

int main() {
    D *a[3];

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        a[i] = new D;
        a[i]->b = i+1;
    }

    cout << "Sum is " << sum((B **)a, 3) << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      delete a[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note that I still had to cast from `D **` to `B **` because that conversion still can cause potentially unsafe stuff. A cast wouldn't be necessary if you had declared the array as a `B *[3]` to begin with:

```
int sum(B *a[], int count) {

    int sum = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        sum += a[i]->b;
    }

    return sum;
}

int main() {
    B *a[3];

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        a[i] = new D;
        a[i]->b = i+1;
    }

    cout << "Sum is " << sum(a, 3) << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      delete a[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Or you could use templates:

```
template <class T>
int sum(T *a[], int count) {

    int sum = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        sum += a[i]->b;
    }

    return sum;
}

int main() {
    D *a[3];

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        a[i] = new D;
        a[i]->b = i+1;
    }

    cout << "Sum is " << sum(a, 3) << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      delete a[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Templates would also work for your original non-pointer way of doing it:

```
template <class T>
int sum(T a[], int count) {

    int sum = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        sum += a[i].b;
    }

    return sum;
}

int main() {
    D a[3];

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        a[i].b = i+1;
    }

    cout << "Sum is " << sum(a, 3) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `sum((B **)a, 3)` This is simply undefined behaviour.

Answer (score -1):

Your proposed solution is actually the correct one but you might want to make B abstract using the virtual keyword.
Another alternative would be to redefine your sum function and make it accept D objects.

An intuitive way to explain why your original implementation will not work is the following:

In the body of sum we have this line of code:

`sum += a[i].b;`  where a is a pointer to objects of type B.

That means that in order to get the element at index `i` we need to add 
`i * sizeof(B)` to the base address a. However this address in now wrong, instead we needed the address `i * sizeof(D)`.

By declaring your pointer type to B this problem is fixed.

By the way you might also want to make your b variable protected and the d one private, then provide getters.